# Overlapping ribbons in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

so when I use the geom rect tool get a ribbon on my graph they are overlapping even though I have defined their limits etc. Any help appreciated 
Thanks

```
primary.P<-c(0.105,0.104,0.106,0.099,0.1,0.095)
groupP<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
sdP<-c(0.004,0.004,0.004,0.004,0.004,0.004)
p.p.dataframe<-data.frame(primary.P,groupP,sdP,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  

    #the plot
ggplot(p.p.dataframe)+
geom_rect(xmin = 0, xmax = 10, ymin = 0, ymax = 0.036, fill="blue", alpha = .1)+
geom_rect(xmin = 0, xmax = 10, ymin =0.036, ymax = 0.069, fill="green", alpha= .1)+
geom_rect(xmin = 0, xmax = 10, ymin = 0.0361, ymax = 0.173, fill="yellow", alpha = .1)+
geom_rect(xmin = 0, xmax = 10, ymin =0.0174, ymax = 1, fill="orange", alpha = .1)+
geom_bar( aes(x=groupP, y=primary.P), stat="identity", fill="darkgrey", alpha=0.9) +
labs(y=expression(bold(Phosphate~"("*mg~N~L^-1*")")), x=expression(bold("Group")))+
geom_errorbar( aes(x=group, ymin=primary.P-sdP, ymax=primary.P+sdP), width=0.4, 
 colour="orange", alpha=0.9, size=1.3)
```

Comment: You have a typo error in your last `geom_rect`. Try with `ymin = 0.174`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to overlap. I think you set the ymin of your green and yellow rectangles to be the same number.

```
ggplot(p.p.dataframe)+
  geom_rect(xmin = 0, xmax = 10, 
            ymin = 0, ymax = 0.036, 
            fill = "blue", alpha = .1)+
  geom_rect(xmin = 0, xmax = 10, 
            ymin = 0.036, ymax = 0.069, 
            fill = "green", alpha = .1)+
  geom_rect(xmin = 0, xmax = 10, 
            ymin = 0.069, ymax = 0.173, 
            fill = "yellow", alpha = .1)+
  geom_rect(xmin = 0, xmax = 10, 
            ymin = 0.173, ymax = 1, 
            fill = "orange", alpha = .1)+
  geom_bar(aes(x = groupP, y = primary.P), 
           stat = "identity", fill = "darkgrey", alpha = 0.9)
  labs(y = expression(bold(Phosphate~"("*mg~N~L^-1*")")), 
       x = expression(bold("Group")))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = groupP, 
                    ymin = primary.P-sdP, 
                    ymax = primary.P+sdP), 
                width = 0.4, colour = "orange", alpha = 0.9, size = 1.3)
```